# What is this "Data Conversion Warning" and how to solve it?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, numpy-ndarray

I'm a newbie to machine learning, and while trying to convert categorical data to numerical data using labelEncoder, I encountered this problem:

```
"ConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel()."
```

On the error message, it mentioned using `ravel()`. But I'm not sure how to apply it, please help, Thank you!

Code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder 
lbl=LabelEncoder()

data["gender_code"]=lbl.fit_transform(data[["gender"]])
data["race/ethnicity_code"]=lbl.fit_transform(data[["race/ethnicity"]])
data["parental level of education_code"]=lbl.fit_transform(data[["parental level of education"]])
data["lunch_code"]=lbl.fit_transform(data[["lunch"]])
data["test preparation course_code"]=lbl.fit_transform(data[["test preparation course"]])
```

Comment: In addition to the answers, you can also use `OrdinalEncoder` instead, which is the exact `LabelEncoder` but for 2D data (n_samples, n_features) and can handle `data[["gender"]]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a subset of the dataframe. `LabelEncoder` expects an input of shape `(num_samples,)` but you are sending `(num_samples, 1)`

Using this should remove the error-
`data["gender_code"]=lbl.fit_transform(data["gender"])`

Notice there are 1 set of square brackets instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

On the line where you have the error, try using `data["COLNAME"]` (1D) instead of `data[["COLNAME"]]` (2D)